# texture analysis statistic, feature extraction for detection object in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

i have a project that can detect a object from picture.it used backpropagation scale conjugate gradient for training. i used 10 component for input. r,g,b, standard deviation, entropy, threshold( Onsu method), glcm that contains contrast, homogeneity,correlation and energy. i manually extract them. i have 100 input. 50 are object, 50 are not object.it's difficult to still maintain manually method. so i want to use loop and array. i use 2 folder for file object and not object. how to extract file in 2 folder?
First folder: C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\MATLAB\object
second folder:C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\non object

this is my coding. i manually write them until 100. can u help me to group them in array and looping them?

```
kl=imread('1.jpg');
g=rgb2gray(kl);
rgb=mean(mean(kl));
r1=rgb(:,:,1);
g1=rgb(:,:,2);
b1=rgb(:,:,3);
std1=std2(g);
entropy1=entropy(g);
tres=graythresh(g);
glcm=graycomatrix(g);
F=graycoprops(glcm,{'Contrast','Homogeneity','Correlation','Energy'});
```

i hope u can give solution. pls help me.

Answer (score 3):

If all your files are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., then you can do the following:

```
for i = 1:50
  fileName = sprintf('%d.jpg', i);
  kl = imread(fileName);

  ... the rest of your code...

end
```

Answer (score 3):

If, in addition to looping over the images in each directory using [@Dima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063347/texture-analysis-statistic-feature-extraction-for-detection-object-in-matlab/3063399#3063399)'s solution, you also want to loop over the two directories, you can do the following:

```
dirNames = {'C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\MATLAB\object','C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\non object'};

for directory = dirNames %# loops directly over the elements of the cell array dirNames
   fileList = dir(fullfile(directory{1},'*.jpg')); %# list all jpgs in the directory
   for iFile = 1:length(fileList)
       %# read the ith file
       kl = imread(fullfile(directory{1},fileList(iFile).name));

       %# do the calculations here

   end
end
```